# What governs the longevity/availability of Bulk Data Load Job batch View Request and View Result links?

Tags: bulk-api

In pushing Bulk Data Load Jobs via Mulesoft, I've relied heavily on being able to inspect the results of jobs as they run via the Bulk Data Load Job Detail page in the Auto-Chunked Batches section. This is especially true when rows fail, of course.

Recently I've noticed that the jobs finish and the result links are not visible:
[image]

Querying the **bulkJobFailedResults** API with the Job ID with Postman returns something like:

```
{
    "message": "Job id: \t7508c00000FgBQ9 not found "
}
```

And the Postman console shows:

```
GET http://evy-salesforce-sapi.us-e2.cloudhub.io/api/bulkJobFailedResults/%097508c00000FgBQ9
200
334 ms

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalFields')
```

This is in pretty much real time, immediately after the job closes, so it's not a question of the 7 day retention limit being crossed. Is there a separate retention limit for result retrieval? Is there a way to govern it?

Or if there's some other reason the results are inaccessible (the "cannot read properties of undefined" is a bit ambiguous), is there documentation somewhere describing how to determine what went wrong?

Comment: You have a tab (encoded as `%09`) n your job id. Remove it and it'll work: `GET http://evy-salesforce-sapi.us-e2.cloudhub.io/api/bulkJobFailedResults/7...`

Comment: Yeah, the tab was an artifact of the cut-and-paste, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was Bulk 1 vs Bulk 2 and my own misunderstanding of the api edge. Using this Trailhead project I learned how to do it right:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-connect-postman-to-salesforce/set-up-and-connect-postman